# Прослушивание QClipboard глобально

Tags: c++, qt, macos

Хочу глобально слушать события буфера обмена в системе. В `Qt` для этого есть специальных класс – `QClipboard`. Используется примерно так:

```
main_widget::main_widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
    connect(clipboard, &QClipboard::dataChanged, this, &main_widget::slot_data_changed);
}
void main_widget::slot_data_changed()
{
    const QMimeData *mime_data = clipboard->mimeData();
    if (mime_data->hasText())
    {
        QString value = clipboard->text();
        qDebug() << value;
    }
}
```

Однако есть проблема. Сигнал `QClipboard::dataChanged` будет послан только когда активируется окно приложения. В моем случае это важно, поскольку планирую проводить обработку именно в фоне. Придумал следующее решение:

```
main_widget::main_widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
    clipboard_timer = new QTimer();
    clipboard_timer->setInterval(250);
    clipboard_timer->start();
    connect(clipboard_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &main_widget::slot_check_clipboard);
}
void main_widget::slot_check_clipboard()
{
    const QMimeData *mime_data = clipboard->mimeData();
    if (mime_data->hasText())
    {
        QString value = clipboard->text();
        qDebug() << value;
    }
}
```

Проще говоря, проверять буфер обмена по таймеру. Это решение работает отлично, однако это **очень** неэффективно и может вызвать огромные проблемы. Есть ли какое-то решение этой проблемы?

Comment: Расшифруйте мысль `Сигнал QClipboard::dataChanged будет послан только когда активируется окно приложения. В моем случае это важно, поскольку планирую проводить обработку именно в фоне`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin ну смотри: 
1) свернул приложение
2) скопировал что-то в буфер обмена (в консоль ничего не вывелось)
3) развернул приложение (в консоль вывелось содержимое буфера обмена)

Comment: @garbart, думаю, это ограничение конкретно macOS, о чём явно сказано в документации... твой случай?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Хм. Да, у меня макось. Стоило это указать. А есть ссылка на этот момент в доке?

Comment: @garbart, да прямо в описании [`QClipboard::dataChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#dataChanged)

Comment: А, ну если мак, то только через таймер )

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то как-то так:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QClipboard* clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
    main_widget main;

    // Сигнал будет срабатывать независимо от окна приложения, 
    // а только от наличия данных буфере обмена
    QObject::connect(clipboard, &QClipboard::dataChanged, [&]() {
         const QMimeData *mime_data = clipboard->mimeData();
         if (mime_data->hasText())
         {
             QString value = clipboard->text();
             qDebug() << value;
             main.set_clipboard_data(value);
         }
    });

    //...

    return a.exec();
}
```